# filter out a string number out of an array in typescript js

Tags: javascript, typescript

Trying to filter out a string number from and array in typescript.
Result should be ["apple"]

```
const arr =  ['1', '2', 'apple'];

const result = arr.filter((k) => parseInt(k) == k)
console.log('result = ', result)
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDGBtA5ARiwGhiwCYCiA1AQQBkBVAUSwF0BuAWAChPRJYEBTCAFcANrDSIEAOgBmASzH8EACmUBrAJSoAfDAAOiCPwCSYKOq0o0m7uAggR-KSJABzZVgHCxqIoS+iUBpAA

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the elements that cannot be converted to a number, you can use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) as your filter condition. (Note: TypeScript expects that the argument to `isNaN` should be a number, so you can attempt to convert each string with the unary plus operator.)

```js
const arr =  ['1', '2', 'apple'];
let res = arr.filter(x => isNaN(+x));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you very cleaver I forgot about the + turning x to a number